# How to create custom alert box using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi can anyone please help me out how to create a custom alert message box using jQuery. Could anyone please send me the link for a jQuery plugin for creating a custom alert box. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Been using this for a long time.

> http://s3.envato.com/files/293712/index.html

Comment: How to download that plugin and use.

Comment: which link should i download and use.

Comment: whether that is paid plugin

Answer (score 0):

Use [jqueryui](/questions/tagged/jqueryui) `dialog()`

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

**Header:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

**Html:**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

[Download](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

Comment: for this no need of plugin

Comment: are you asking to informing me?